# How to merge dataframes together with matching columns side by side?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes with matching keys. I would like to merge them together based on their keys and have the corresponding columns line up side by side. I am not sure how to achieve this as the `pd.merge` displays all columns for the first dataframe and then all columns for the second data frame:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'key': ['a', 'b'], 'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'key': ['a', 'b'], 'col1': [5, 6], 'col2': [7, 8]})

print(pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['key']))

  key  col1_x  col2_x  col1_y  col2_y
0   a       1       3       5       7
1   b       2       4       6       8
```

I am looking for a way to do the same merge and have the columns displays side by side as such:

```
 key  col1_x  col1_y  col2_x  col2_y
0   a       1       5       3       7
1   b       2       6       4       8
```

Any help achieving this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is no order when you merge two dataframes. You should rearrange your columns after they are merged using a separate function.

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with a bit of a shuffle you can sort the columns.

```py
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['key'])
df = df.reindex(columns = sorted(df.columns))
```

or you could do this to maintain the key in the front

```py
cols = list(df.columns)
cols.remove('key')
print(cols)
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['key'])
df = df.reindex(columns = ['key']+sorted(cols))
```